# Custom query to order post by two meta value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have property listing website. I know how to sort posts by meta value but I am in a different situation, Properties have two price meta fields-

1. Normal Price
2. Discounted Price

I am able to sort posts either by Normal Price or Discounted Price but I want WordPress to treat both meta values as one value so if two properties A and B have $4000 and $5000 Normal Price respectively but B has Discounted Price $3500 then B should come before A.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'listing',
            'posts_per_page'    => 15,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'meta_key'          => $meta_prefix . 'price',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'             => 'ASC'
        );
$listings = new WP_Query($args);
```

The Second meta key is `$meta_prefix.'discounted_price'`

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: For a crude option, sort by the normal price + the discounted price. If you want the order to be biased in some way by one of the prices then you will have to specify that bias.

Comment: I am beginner in wordpress, I am able to sort by post by normal price but I don't know how can I order by normal price + discounted price.

Comment: No experience of wordpress, but if you have access to use sql then just put _ORDER BY (normal_price + discounted_price)_ at the end of the query.

Comment: @user2839914 . . . Try editing your question and showing the query that sorts by normal price.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have edited my question and added my WP_Query with arguments.

Comment: You cannot sort this way in wordpress. Drop the sorting in your query and then use `usort` on the returned array to sort accordingly

Comment: @PieterGoosen- If I sort it using usort then I need to pull all listing posts and WordPress pagination will not work. (I think), please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create the following function , which will allow you to sort by two fields:

You can put it in the file functions:

```
function customorderby($orderby) {
   return 'mt1.meta_value, mt2.meta_value ASC';
}
```

After WP_Query before you add the filter to that function and when you finish you delete, Sample:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','customorderby');
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'    => 'listing',
    'posts_per_page'    => 15,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'meta_key'     => $meta_prefix . 'price',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key' =>  $meta_prefix . 'price',
        ),
        array(
           'key' => $meta_prefix.'discounted_price',
       )
    )
));
remove_filter('posts_orderby','customorderby');
```

Comment: Thank you, though I solved my problem earlier. I used same way. Thank you again :)